# add ionic2 rating in alert controller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an alert controller where i want to add the ionic2 rating component.

here's my code I am already tried:

```
  addRating(){
    let body='<rating starIconName="md-star" emptyStarIconName="md-star-outline" halfStarIconName="md-star-half"></rating>';
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: '',
      subTitle: body,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {

                 //do something

      });
    });
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }

      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

But, the alert controller does not shows the rating option. it only shows blank. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: subtitle is just a text field.. Dont think it parses html... Suggest you use a modal in this case

Comment: Modal is my second option. By the way subtitle actually parses html. It's probably because of the <rating> tag or something, i donno..

Comment: hmm.. is it an angular component? Maybe thats what is not parsed in subtitle string

Comment: I think this is not yet possible. You need to use custom modal for showing alert component. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771443/add-ionic2-rating-in-alert-controller